# How can I filter a pcap file by specific protocol using python?

Tags: python, filter, pcap, scapy

I have some pcap files and I want to filter by protocol, i.e., if I want to filter by HTTP  protocol, anything but HTTP packets will remain in the pcap file.

There is a tool called [openDPI](http://www.opendpi.org/), and it's perfect for what I need, but there is no wrapper for python language.

Does anyone knows any python modules that can do what I need?

Thanks

**Edit 1:**

HTTP filtering was just an example, there is a lot of protocols that I want to filter.

**Edit 2:**

I tried Scapy, but I don't figure how to filter correctly. The filter only accepts Berkeley Packet Filter expression, i.e., I can't apply a msn, or HTTP, or another specific filter from upper layer. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 20):

A quick example using Scapy, since I just wrote one:

```
pkts = rdpcap('packets.pcap')
ports = [80, 25]
filtered = (pkt for pkt in pkts if
    TCP in pkt and
    (pkt[TCP].sport in ports or pkt[TCP].dport in ports))
wrpcap('filtered.pcap', filtered)
```

That will filter out packets that are neither HTTP nor SMTP. If you want all the packets *but* HTTP and SMTP, the third line should be:

```
filtered = (pkt for pkt in pkts if
    not (TCP in pkt and
    (pkt[TCP].sport in ports or pkt[TCP].dport in ports)))
wrpcap('filtered.pcap', filtered)
```

Answer (score 14):

I know this is a super-old question, but I just ran across it thought I'd provide ***my*** answer.   This is a problem I've encountered several times over the years, and I keep finding myself falling back to [dpkt](http://code.google.com/p/dpkt/).  Originally from the very capable [dugsong](http://monkey.org/~dugsong/), dpkt is primarily a packet creation/parsing library.  I get the sense the pcap parsing was an afterthought, but it turns out to be a very useful one, because parsing pcaps, IP, TCP and and TCP headers is straightforward.  It's parsing all the higher-level protocols that becomes the time sink! (I wrote my own python pcap parsing library before finding dpkt)

The documentation on using the pcap parsing functionality is a little thin.  Here's an example from my files:

```
import socket
import dpkt
import sys
pcapReader = dpkt.pcap.Reader(file(sys.argv[1], "rb"))
for ts, data in pcapReader:
    ether = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(data)
    if ether.type != dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP: raise
    ip = ether.data
    src = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.src)
    dst = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.dst)
    print "%s -> %s" % (src, dst)
```

Hope this helps the next guy to run across this post!

Comment: Looks like dpkt is not maintained anymore. http://code.google.com/p/dpkt/issues/list Any other suggestions to parse pcap file? which is not a pita to install on mac and linux?

Comment: a package like dpkt is never "complete" - the environment is too dynamic.  you've got to be prepared to dig in when you need to.   I've never had a problem with the install on either Mac or Linux, even within the last couple months: just `python setup.py install`.  Double-check your assumptions, something else is likely wonky somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

sniff supports a offline option wherein you can provide the pcap file as input. This way you can use the filtering advantages of sniff command on pcap file.

```
>>> packets = sniff(offline='mypackets.pcap')
>>>
>>> packets
<Sniffed: TCP:17 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>
```

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 4):

Something along the lines of

```
from pcapy import open_offline
from impacket.ImpactDecoder import EthDecoder
from impacket.ImpactPacket import IP, TCP, UDP, ICMP

decoder = EthDecoder()

def callback(jdr, data):
    packet = decoder.decode(data)
    child = packet.child()
    if isinstance(child, IP):
        child = packet.child()
        if isinstance(child, TCP):
            if child.get_th_dport() == 80:
                print 'HTTP'

pcap = open_offline('net.cap')
pcap.loop(0, callback)
```

using

http://oss.coresecurity.com/projects/impacket.html

Comment: Error in the example. Second child should be = child.child() not = packet.child()

Answer (score 3):

Try [pylibpcap](http://pylibpcap.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: But I don't want to parse each packet to check for the protocol that I want, I want a simple solution (like openDPI). Also, I don't want to worry about "magic number" of all protocols that exists. If there is no solution, then I will have to do that. Thanks

Comment: A couple thoughts: 1. most of the python pcap libraries allow you to set a BPF filter on the captured packets. HTTP is an easy filter `tcp port 80`. 
2. You could use Wireshark or a similar GUI to isolate the packets that you want, save those to a dumpfile and use pylibpcap or another of these libraries to operate on them.

Comment: There is no way besides "parsing each packet". You can have a program which does it behind the scenes for you, that's all you can hope.

Answer (score 2):

to filter in/out a specific protocol you have to do a per packet analysis otherwise you could miss some http traffic on a non-conventional port that is flowing in your network. of course if you want a loose system, you could check just for source and destination port number but that wont give you exact results. you have to look for specific feature of a protocol like GET, POST, HEAD etc keywords for HTTP and others for other protocol and check each TCP packets.

Comment: Yeah, it is not magical and easy thing as I thought initially. Scapy solve my specific problem as far I remember. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the same using @nmichaels method, but it becomes cumbersome when I want to iterate it over multiple protocols. I tried finding ways to read the .pcap file and then filter it but found no help.
Basically, when one reads a .pcap file there is no function in Scapy which allows to filter these packets, on the other hand using a command like,

```
a=sniff(filter="tcp and ( port 25 or port 110 )",prn=lambda x: x.sprintf("%IP.src%:%TCP.sport% -> %IP.dst%:%TCP.dport%  %2s,TCP.flags% : %TCP.payload%"))
```

helps to filter but only while sniffing.

If anyone knows of any other method where we can use a BPF syntax instead of the for statement?

Comment: You can generalize my method to use an actual generator instead of a generator expression. That should make for relatively clear code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my [example](https://gist.github.com/viz-prakash/544ef1195b34ec84f4ff2d2b77b47d30) of pcap parsing using scapy. It also has some relevant code for performance testing and some other stuff.